# Why does AuthenticationManager.Login throw "object not set" exception?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've got the following code behind a WCF Service:

```
if (Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("sitecore\\" + username, password, false)) 
{ 
  // do something 
}
```

But I'm getting an "Object not set" exception, with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase(String userName, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc) 
at System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext sc, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider) 
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) 
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.set_Item(String propertyName, Object value) 
at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.SetInternal(String propertyName, Object value) 
at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.set_Item(String propertyName, Object value) 
at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) 
at Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.SetPropertyValueCore(String propertyName, Object value) 
at Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.set_SerializedData(Object value) 
at Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.get_CustomProperties() 
at Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.GetCustomProperty(String propertyName) 
at Sitecore.Security.SecurityUtil.GetUserDigestCredentials(User user, Boolean withoutDomain) 
at Sitecore.Security.SecurityUtil.UpdateDigestCredentials(String username, String password) 
at Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) 
at System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password) 
at Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) 
at Sitecore.Security.Authentication.MembershipAuthenticationProvider.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistent) 
at Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistent) 
at BaillieGifford.Code.services.DR.LoginToSiteCore(String username, String password) in c:\Dev\Development-Websites\Mainwebsite2012-DR\Code\services\DR.svc.cs:line 26 
at SyncInvokeLoginToSiteCore(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

The stack trace seems to indicate that there is a problem (somewhere) with properties on the users, but doesnt exactly give any indication as to what ...

Any thoughts?

Update:

Profile bit from web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="sql" enabled="true" inherits="Sitecore.Security.UserProfile, Sitecore.Kernel">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="sql" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore"/>
<add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingProfileProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/profile"/>
</providers>
<properties>
<clear/>
<add type="System.String" name="SC_UserData"/>
</properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: It's not something stupid like the username or password is blank or incorrect is it? Can you replicate this with a hard coded user value and password?

Comment: Fraid not - checked that :(  Both values are being set, and I get the same error with hard coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception can occur when you use custom profile provider and it is not set as default provider.
Check whether defaultProvider is set for the  in the web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="CustomizedProfileProvider"> <-- CHECK IF DEFAULT PROVIDER IS SET

  <providers>

    <clear/>

    <add name="CustomizedProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"

         connectionStringName="database"

         applicationName="/app"/>

  </providers>

</profile>
```

Also the method `System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase` requires `HttpContext.Current` to be set or `Ewt.Trace` to be disabled (see the code below) but there is no `HttpContext` in WCF.

```
private void GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase(string userName, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted && EtwTrace.IsTraceEnabled(4, 8))
    {
        EtwTrace.Trace(EtwTraceType.ETW_TYPE_PROFILE_BEGIN, HttpContext.Current.WorkerRequest);
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Try to disable tracing, maybe it would help.

Comment: Just updated the question to include the profile section from web.config; the provider is set as default it seems (although I've not changed this bit)

Comment: Added more info about WCF and HttpContext. Looks like the object which is not set is HttpContext.Current.

Comment: Ah! Perfect - that's the pointer I needed. I've enabled ASP.NET Compatibility for the WCF Service, and its work - cheers!